# Upload a file, make sure it's a pdf, then use Swiftmailer

Tags: php, html, forms, file-io, swiftmailer

I've been struggling with some code for a while now. I have an html form that looks like this (It's really rugged, I know. Just trying to get it to work):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<table>

<tr>
    <td> Name </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="name" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Email </td> 
    <td> <input type="text" name="email" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr>

<tr>
    <td> Title of Article &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="title" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Course </td>
    <td>
    <select name="course">
    <option>CEG - Computer Architecture I</option>
    <option>BIO - General Biology I</option>
    <option>BIO - General Biology II</option>
    <option>BIO - Introduction to Human Genetics</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> File </td>
    <td> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></td>
</tr>

<tr> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr>

<tr>
    <td valign="top"> Additional Info </td>
    <td><textarea rows="3" cols="40" name="info"></textarea></td>
</tr>

</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="agree"> I agree to the points outlined above and am willing to submit my article <br>
<    input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

This form calls itself, this is what I have up to now:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ( !isset($_POST['agree'])   || 
         !isset($_POST['name'])    || 
         !isset($_POST['email'])   ||  
         !isset($_POST['title'])   ||  
         !isset($_POST['course'])  ||  
         !isset($_POST['file'])) {
        echo 'Please complete all required fields<br>';
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $course = $_POST['course'];
        $file = $_POST['file'];

        $message  = "Name: ".$name."\n";
        $message .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n";
        $message .= "Title of Article: ".$title."\n";
        $message .= "Program: ".$course."\n\n";
        $message .= "Additional Info: ".$info;

        if ( !preg_match("/.pdf$/", $file) ) {
            echo 'Article must be in pdf format<br>';
            exit;
        }

        require_once 'include/swift_required.php';

        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $swift = Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('New Institutum Submission')
            ->setFrom(array($email => $name))
            ->setTo(array('sub@f33r.com'))
            ->setBody($message)
            ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file));

        $result = $mailer->send($swift);
        if ($result) {  echo 'Article sent. Please allow required amount of time to review submission.\n';
                        echo 'You will be contacted by email when we go over your submission.'; }
        else {          echo 'Message failed'; }
    }
}
```

I'm using regex to check if it s a pdf file, but I doubt that's the correct way of doing things (as someone could just rename a file with a pdf extension). Also, I haven't implemented a way to upload the file temporarily yet. This is assuming I need to upload the file locally before using swiftmailer to add it as an attachment (right?).

Am I at least on the right track? I've never really dealt with PHP in this way.

Needs some debugging:

```
        # Create the message
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $course = $_POST['course'];
        $file = $_POST['file'];

        $message  = "Name: ".$name."\n";
        $message .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n";
        $message .= "Title of Article: ".$title."\n";
        $message .= "Program: ".$course."\n\n";
        $message .= "Additional Info: ".$info;

        # Upload temporary files
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        $uploaddir = '/home/public/uploads/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) == false) {
            echo 'Could not move file';
            exit;
        }

        if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            echo 'Not a pdf file';
            unlink($uploadfile);
            exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>`, which will also kill the upload before it even has a chance to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to check the file-extension as it could be manipulated.

Instead, the way to go is checking for the MIME-Type. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) (example 2).
The MIME-type of a PDF-file is `application/pdf`

Also note [Saxoier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798880/saxoier)'s comment:

> This answer implies that it is safe to rely on the Content-Type. The
>   best way to check a file if it contains valid content is to parse it
>   with the specific parser (e.g. images: [GD](http://php.net/book.image)). If none is available
>   then do not accept files who can be harmful (e.g. *.php [use a
>   whitelist of save files - not a blacklist]).

Comment: How do I check the mime-type of a pdf? Can this be handled by swiftmailer?

Comment: I added the PDF MIME-Type to my post. Also check the Link I posted.

Comment: The MIME type as available in `$_FILES[file][type]` is no less susceptible to tampering as the file extension. (In fact most user-agents just map the file extension to media types.)

Comment: @mario - Do I need to upload the file to the server before doing the check? It looks like I need to do `finfo_open` before checking the MIME type, which would require an absolute path on the server.

Comment: No, you check the MIME-Type of the uploaded file. See the posted link on how this is done.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth - I added some code to my post. I can't seem to move the file correctly.

Comment: I made a new post, due to this being a new issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976993/php-cant-upload-file-from-html-form

Comment: @Saxoier sure it can also be manipulated. But what would you check for?

Comment: @Lukas Knuth: Your answer implies that it is safe to rely on the Content-Type. The best way to check a file if it contains valid content is to parse it with the specific parser (e.g. images: [GD](http://php.net/book.image)). If none is available then do not accept files who can be harmful (e.g. *.php [use a whitelist of save files - not a blacklist]).