# PHP can't upload file from HTML form

Tags: php, html, file-upload, file-io

This is how I handle my form:

```
        # Create the message
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $course = $_POST['course'];
        $file = $_POST['file'];

        $message  = "Name: ".$name."\n";
        $message .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n";
        $message .= "Title of Article: ".$title."\n";
        $message .= "Program: ".$course."\n\n";
        $message .= "Additional Info: ".$info;

        # Upload temporary files
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        $uploaddir = '/home/public/uploads/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) == false) {
            echo 'Could not move file';
            exit;
        }

        if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            echo 'Not a pdf file';
            unlink($uploadfile);
            exit;
        }
```

The end product is hopefully sending an email with the file as an attachment. Right now I'm failing and getting the "Could not move file" message I built in. Is there an obvious reason why? `$file` is what I get from a file dialog in HTML (`input type="file"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:
1. Is the form set to:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="INSERT ACTION">
```

2. Is the folder your posting the file to, is it set to 777?

Comment: Yeah I chmoded that folder to 777, I added the enctype and I'm just working out a couple syntax errors. I think this might be the issue.

Comment: The second I added the enctype, it seems that nothing is getting stored in $_POST .... is this normal?

Comment: Yes actually. You need to use $_FILE[''];

Comment: @Jake He should still get the other form data in `$_POST`. Also, it's `$_FILES` (plural)

Comment: @Phil Hmm, actually now that I think about it, that is true. odd. And yes he is right, it's `$_FILES` Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Yeah $_POST doesnt give anything for file :) Thanks for your help, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your form needs to have the appropriate `enctype` attribute set, ie

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=... >
```

#### Update

A couple of suggestions...

1. Check the file type and do any other general validation *before* you move the uploaded file. That should be your last step.
2. Can't remember exactly right now but I don't think you'll get anything useful (or at all) in the `$_POST['file']` value. Use the `$_FILES` array for all uploaded file data.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll use regex to check the extension at least. Any ideas about the comment I posted below?

Comment: @Max You don't need to change your validation method, just move the "PDF check" block above the "move uploaded file" block

Comment: Yeah I just finished the code. It works flawlessly, thanks :) I'm performing all checks before I upload the file.